# Are onion and garlic prohibited in Ayurveda?

Tags: food, ayurveda

It's not a question but needs an answer . I need a list of bad things that happen when you consume onion and garlic. Because I personally don't like them since I heard that they make your anger worse, and that's why I don't eat them because my anger destroys my peace ,so I want a list of bad effects of these so that if anyone argues with me about their benefits I can tell them the bad effects.

Edit : any support of any Hindu story to make my point strong that in hindu dharma we should not consume Onion and garlic OR some story related to in which hindu god doesn't approve of things and foods with Onion and garlic in it.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Do you want to know about the effects of garlic/onions on our health? Then your question is off-topic on this site. It is better posed for PhysicalFitness.SE or Seasoned Advice.

Comment: I want to know it's bad effects. Not only on health even on mind and every bad effect. On anything.

Comment: This Q is off topic for site!